# Plugin class Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\StatePlugin doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, composer, plugin, magento-core

I just update my Magento 2.2 core components using the command `composer update -vvvv` and then I got a lot of updates which caused this issue below when I tried to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.
[image: Plugin class Magento NewRelicReporting StatePlugin doesn't exist]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin is probably cached by redis. Flush your redis cache using the following command:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Comment: For those who are using docker, you can use this command: 

```bash
docker exec -it container-name redis-cli FLUSHALL
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/dimasch/57b7cee3f7f9d274253d